# pattern matching in a single line in perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I have a scalar whose value will be like this.

```
Sun Sep  9 12:14:56 2012 : [Pro] Write to file(/root/mesh/MeshBed/trunk/meshproc/neighInfo/neighbors-list_152.    14.189.6) : #ip=152.14.189.99 neighinfo=NULL mac=06:02:6F:A7:3E:BC#
```

I want to take the Timefield (12:14:38) and the ip (152.14.189.99) from this in perl. I tried using this..

```
$p =~ /ip\=(\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\d+)/;
print $1;
```

This is throwing compilation error. Can anyone solve this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $p = "Sun Sep  9 12:14:56 2012 : [Pro] Write to file(/root/mesh/MeshBed/trunk/meshproc/neighInfo/neighbors-list_152.    14.189.6) : #ip=152.14.189.99 neighinfo=NULL mac=06:02:6F:A7:3E:BC#";

$p =~ /ip\=(\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\d+)/;

print $1;
```

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure it's a compilation error and not a runtime error?

Comment: Global symbol "$p" requires explicit package name at ./patternmatching.pl line 8.
Execution of ./patternmatching.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: What is the full text of your script? You are looking for the regexp within the variable `$p` which is never defined.

Comment: `$p` *has* to contain the string you are matching, i.e. the log entry. *And* you should declare *all* your variables with `my`, what does not seem to be the case. How are you doing IO?

Answer (score 4):

When run, this produces the answer I expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $p = "Sun Sep  9 12:14:56 2012 : [Pro] Write to file(/root/mesh/MeshBed/trunk/meshproc/neighInfo/neighbors-list_152.    14.189.6) : #ip=152.14.189.99 neighinfo=NULL mac=06:02:6F:A7:3E:BC#";


print "Time: $1; IP: $2\n"
    if ($p =~ /(\d+:\d+:\d+) .*ip=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/);
```

The regex for the IP address no longer requires a leading dot and does expect a dot between the third and fourth numbers.  The regex for the time is pretty straight-forward too.

The output is:

```
Time: 12:14:56; IP: 152.14.189.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the compilation error which is impossible to figure out without more context, here's what you could do, given that your scalar is called `$p`:

```
my ($time, $ip) = $p =~ / (\d+[.:]\d+[.:]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g;
```

**EDIT:** This works for your new string format:

```
my ($time, $ip) = $p =~ /(\d+:\d+:\d+).+ip=((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)/;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that match `14.189.6` as well? Also, the dot does not have to be escaped in a character class, i.e. `\.` eq `[.]`

Comment: 1 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
  2 $p = "Sun Sep  9 12:14:56 2012 : [Pro] Write to file(/root/mesh/MeshBed/trunk/meshproc/neighInfo/neighbors-list_152.14.189.6) : #ip=152.14.189.99     neighinfo=NULL mac=06:02:6F:A7:3E:BC#";
  3 ($time, $ip) = $p =~ / (\d+[\.:]\d+[\.:]\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g;
  4 print $time $ip;
Still I get error print() on unopened filehandle 12:14:56 at ./patternmatching.pl line 4.

Comment: @amon: Yes, it would. I tested it with the original data `Sun Sep 9 12:14:38 2012 : [Rep] Reply back to 152.14.189.99 / msg: #he#llo_reply_disc mac=00:02:55:70:00:00# / repeat:1`.

Comment: @Raj: Replace `print $time $ip;` with `print "$time $ip\n";`

Comment: Or put a comma after the time: `print $time, $ip;` (but you probably want better formatting and a newline, so the alternative suggestion of `printf "$time $ip\n";` is more sensible).

Comment: @Raj: don't try posting a script in a comment.  You can add it to your own question.  Just be careful to add without destroying the original material.